# What is the difference between &address + sizeof(type) and &address + 1?

Tags: c, unix, memory-management, malloc, mmap

I am trying do re-code malloc function.
Let's imagine that we have a struct like this :

```
typedef struct      s_block
{
    char            is_free;
    size_t          size;
    struct s_block  *next;
    void            *memory;
}                   t_block;
```

I allocate a page of memory with mmap, and I cast it into a big t_block.
Then, I have 1 block of size 4064 (4096 - size of t_block).
If I call my malloc with a size 12 for example, here is what I do :

```
block->next = &block + 1 + size // Setting the next block
block->next->size = block->size - size - sizeof(t_block); // 4064 - 12 - 32
block->size = size; // 12
block->is_free = NOT_FREED;
block->memory = &block + 1;
block->next->memory = &(block->next) + 1;
block->next->next = NULL;
block->next->is_free = FREE;
```

I often have issues when I use + 1 or + sizeof(t_block).
So, what is the difference between :

```
block->next = &block + 1 + size;
```

and :

```
block->next = &block + sizeof(t_block) + size;
```

?

Comment: Neither of those statements looks correct.   Should be `block->next = &block + sizeof(s_block)`, assuming the blocks are contiguous.

Comment: `&block + sizeof(block)`  will produce a pointer to the address of `block` plus `sizeof(block)*sizeof(block)` bytes.

Comment: But there's a good chance those blocks are *not* contiguous unless you're storing them in an array, which kinda defeats the purpose of a linked list.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I don't think the blocks are contiguous - the allocated memory appears that it might be located *between* blocks.  That would be wrong, as it incorrectly assumes that a `struct s_block` has no alignment restrictions.

Comment: Actually the blocks should be contiguous:
|t_block metadata|___memory_asked___|t_block metadata|___memory_asked___| etc...
the first block next link to the next block, that is at position &block + size of the block metadata + size of the asked memory.
The blocks should be contiguous as I placed them in a memory page I got with mmap()

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `block` is declared as a `t_block *` and that you want `size` bytes between this block and the next, neither does what you expect.  Since `&block` is the address of a pointer, any pointer arithmetic done on it operates based on the size of a pointer, not the size of the struct.

What you actually want is:

```
block->next = (t_block *)((char *)block + sizeof(t_block) + size);
```

By first casting `block` to a `char *`, any pointer arithmetic done on it works on single bytes, not a multiple of the structure size.  So we start at the address of the block, move up `sizeof(t_block)` bytes to the start of the user's memory, then `size` more bytes to the end of that memory and the start of the next block.

Also, due to the alignment requirements of your struct, you'll need to make sure the next block is aligned properly.  You can do that as follows:

```
size_t block_align = (sizeof(t_block) - (size % sizeof(t_block))) % sizeof(t_block);
block->next = (t_block *)((char *)block + sizeof(t_block) + block_align + size);
```

Comment: Creating block->next worked, thank you !
But for the alignment, would not it be easier with something like this ? :  

`size += sizeof(t_block);
while (size % 16)
        size++;`

Comment: @Elynad Assuming `sizeof(t_block)` is 16, then that would work as well.

Comment: No, the `sizeof(t_block)` is 32, but is not alignment based on the processor ? I put 16 as my processor read 16 bytes each "turn"

Answer (score 0):

`((Type*)(p)) + n == ((char*)(p)) + sizeof(Type)*n`

Arithmetic (i.e., really just addition/subtraction) on typed pointers is scaled by the size of the pointed-to type (`sizeof(char)` is defined to be 1).